# Error inesperado después de registrar wmp.dll en una aplicación VB6.0

Tags: windows, vb6

٩(◕‿◕｡)۶

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en VB6.0 que utiliza el control "Windows Media Player" (wmp.dll) para reproducir archivos multimedia. Recientemente, me encontré con un problema en el que la aplicación mostraba un mensaje de error relacionado con wmp.dll al intentar abrir la función de reproducción. (´；ω；｀)

Para solucionar esto, seguí la recomendación de registrar el wmp.dll utilizando el comando 'regsvr32'. Después de hacer esto, el mensaje de error anterior relacionado con wmp.dll desapareció, pero ahora me enfrento a un "error inesperado" al intentar abrir la aplicación.

He intentado deshacer la registración del wmp.dll y registrarla nuevamente, pero el problema persiste. También he verificado si hay errores de sintaxis en mi código y he comprobado que las referencias y componentes estén correctamente establecidos.

¿Alguien ha experimentado este problema antes o tiene alguna idea de qué podría estar causando este "error inesperado" después de registrar el wmp.dll? ¿Hay algún otro paso que deba seguir para solucionar este problema?

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o consejo que puedan ofrecer. Gracias de antemano. ( •̀ ω •́ )✧

Comment: El error te aparece cuando usas la aplicación compilada (directamente desde el .exe), o desde el IDE??? (o ambos)

Comment: Unicamente me aparece con el exe

Comment: En el mismo computador o en otro?

Comment: Es en el mismo computador, lo extraño es que anteriormente la aplicación funcionaba y de un día a otro dejo de funcionar

Comment: Por probar algo, toma todas las dll del proyecto y copialas en la misma carpeta del .exe

Comment: Lo estuve intentando de diferentes maneras, lo que me funciono fue poner todos los archivos del programa en la carpeta del exe, hasta alli me seguia fallando pero al reiniciar la computadora funciono

Comment: Yo en este tema hace muuucho que no lo veo, pero de lo que recuerdo era que las dll las busca primero en la carpeta del .exe, si no las encuentra las va a buscar en las dll registradas. ¿Por qué puede dar errores? Por versiones distintas en la dll, y porque una dll puede usar otra dll, y puede que esa dll no exista o sea esa otra la que es una versión distinta

Comment: Una sugerencia, evita usar tantos emoji ascii en tus publicaciones, ya que realmente no aportan nada. Piensa que este es un entorno profesional, no una red de *amiguis*.